# output transfer to a new file

Tags: c, combinations

I am a complete noob to c. I have downloaded a code from internet. It generates all possible combination of characters. I want to transfer this output to a text file. I have tried few things but unable to do it. Can anybody suggest me the necessary changes? Here is the code.a

EDIT: I have changed the put command to fputs. i tried all possible combinations.fputs(&str[1],f), fputs("&str[1]" ,"f"), fputs("&str[1]",f) and fputs(&str,"f"). but nothing worked. what to do next?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define MINCHAR 33
#define MAXCHAR 126

char *bruteforce(int passlen, int *ntries);

int main(void) {

    int i, wdlen, counter;
    char *str;
    clock_t start, end;
    double elapsed;
    FILE *myfile;
    myfile = fopen("ranjit.txt","w");

    do {
        printf("Word length... ");
        scanf("%d", &wdlen);
    } while(wdlen<2);

    start = clock();

    bruteforce(wdlen, &counter);

    end = clock();

    elapsed = ((double) (end - start)) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    fprintf(myfile,"\nNum of tries... %d \n",counter);
    fprintf(myfile,"\nTime elapsed... %f seconds\n",elapsed);
    return counter;

}

char *bruteforce(int passlen, int *ntries) {

    int i;
    char *str;
    FILE *f;
    f = fopen("sandip.txt","w");

    *ntries=0;

    passlen++;

    str = (char*)malloc( passlen*sizeof(char) );

    for(i=0; i<passlen; i++) {
        str[i]=MINCHAR;
    }
    str[passlen]='\0';

    while(str[0]<MINCHAR+1) {
        for(i=MINCHAR; i<=MAXCHAR; i++) {
            str[passlen-1]=i;
            (*ntries)++;
            fputs("&str[1]",f);
        }

        if(str[passlen-1]>=MAXCHAR) {
            str[passlen-1]=MINCHAR;
            str[passlen-1-1]++;
        }

        for(i=passlen-1-1; i>=0; i--) {
            if(str[i]>MAXCHAR) {
                str[i]=MINCHAR;
                str[i-1]++;
            }
        }
    }

    return NULL;

}
```

Comment: Using GNU/Linux or other posix compatible system? Then the most simple way is to redirect the output to a file, like ./yourprogram > outfile.txt .. That should also be possible from Windows, but I don't know how.

Comment: @Johan, it works on windows exactly the same way

Comment: thanks for suggestion guys but this method won't work for me.

Comment: Help please. I am struggling since 3 hours on this.

Comment: Wait a second, what is this variable f that you are using with fputs? Post your new code.

Comment: A few extra notes: Don't cast the output of `malloc`, its not needed. Call `free(str);` at the end of `bruteforce` to fix your memory leak.

Comment: I think you have a memory error: You can't set str[passlen] unless you do `str = malloc(sizeof(char) * (passlen + 1))`. I would get into the habit of running Valgrind on your executable to find memory errors like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `puts` with `fputs`, which takes a `FILE*` as its second argument. You will need to pass that in to `bruteforce`.

Comment: question edited guys. I tried fputs as suggested by mathepic. nothing worked. Expecting more suggestions.

Comment: I just tried implementing my suggestion on your code and it works fine.

Comment: @mathepic can u provide me the syntax you tried.When I tried fputs, it stopped to generate output. or the exe stops to work in between.

Comment: It takes time to write large amounts of output. I declared `static FILE* myfile;` at the top instead of in `main`, and used `fputs(&str[1], myfile);`

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, you can use shell redirection to create a file with the output...

```
./myprogram > output.txt
```

Comment: Output of this program will work as input for other, so i can't use this method.

Comment: Use a pipe! `./program1 | ./program2` will work. You can also use `./program1 > tmp && ./program2 < tmp`

Comment: I did not explained it earlier properly. It's like two functions of a program. output of a function will work as input for other. Can't use command line.